# d3.js is missing words

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm using the d3-cloud to visualize some words. Unfortunately, there is an issue: sometimes a word is missing. To investigate the problem I’m using the same 10 words with different (but static) sizes. When I load or reload the page, all 10 words are displayed correctly until one is missing (it seems, that always the same word is missing, but not the one with the largest font). The canvas should be large enough as in over 95% it is shown correctly and when the word is missing, there appears to be an area that is large enough to hold the missing word.

```
d3.layout.cloud().size([w, h])
.words(wordList)
.rotate(function() { return (0);})
.fontSize(function(d) { return fontSize(+d.size); })
.on("end", draw)
.start();
function draw(words) {
d3.select("."+element).remove();
d3.select("#"+element).append("svg")
    .attr("width", w)
    .attr("height", h)
    .attr("class", element)
    .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + w/2 + "," + h/2 + ")")
        .selectAll("text")
            .data(words)
            .enter().append("text")
                .style("font-size", function(d) { return (d.size - 5) + "px"; })
                .style("fill", function(d, i) { return fillColor(d,i); })
                .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
                .attr("transform", function(d) {
                    return "translate(" + [ d.x, d.y] + ")rotate(" + d.rotate + ")"
                })
                .text(function(d) { return d.text; });
```

I checked other questions like [d3.js word missing from word cloud](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26471497/d3-js-word-missing-from-word-cloud) but the solution there is to limit the size of the font (in my case the largest font is displayed) or to increase the visible area. But this does not solve my issue. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. It really is just all down to ensuring every element in your array will fit the bounds of the canvas, and for some data sets that takes some tweaking of the w and h values and the range of font sizes. In my case, I had to reduce the range from [10,100] to [15,30]:

```
fontSize = d3.scale["sqrt"]().range([15, 30]);
```

Set the canvas size to the full window width rather than the div:

```
  //    var w = $("#wordcloud").innerWidth(),
 //     h = $("#wordcloud").innerHeight();
        var w = window.innerWidth,
        h = window.innerHeight;
```

And set the div size to larger than the svg (1280 x 480)

```
<style>
          #wordcloud {
            width: 1300px;
            height: 500px;
          }
</style>
```